# What does ipq_ctl do?

Tags: linux, netfilter

I'm in the process of writing some rust bindings to libipq, and I came across an undocumented function in `libipq.h`: `int ipq_ctl(const struct ipq_handle *h, int request, ...);`. However, this doesn't seem to be documented in the man page (http://linux.die.net/man/3/libipq)

I can't find anything about this on the web (googling `ipq_ctl` is not useful) so I was wondering if you people might know what on earth this function does.

Comment: I think libipq is depreceted but if you look in source code of iptables you will find that in function definition there is a comment it is not implemented and just returns 1.